# setOnMapClickListener

Tags: android, google-maps-api, android-button

Всем привет. Ребята, нужна Ваша помощь! Есть следующий метод:

```
map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0){
                FAB = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
                FAB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                FAB = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
                FAB1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
```

Если кликнуть на карту, то кнопки исчезнут. Как сделать так, чтобы после следующего нажатия по карте они снова появлялись. Любая помощь будет бесценной!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в 2 строчки, без переменных =)

```
map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0){
             FAB.setVisibility(FAB.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
             FAB1.setVisibility(FAB1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        }
        });
```

Comment: краткость - сестра таланта, спасибо!:)

Answer (score 1):

можно хранить `boolean` переменную, назвать типа `isFirstClick = false`, тогда логика будет такой

```
map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0){
                 if (!isFirstClick){
                     FAB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                     FAB1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                     isFirstClick = true;
                  }else{
                     FAB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                     FAB1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                     isFirstClick = false;
                  }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ! чет я затупил....